# Can you select the current state of a styling element in sass?

Tags: css, sass

I want to be able to change the color of the text inside a btn:hover to either black or white, based on whether the background is darker/lighter. Is there a way to do this in the scss file? Or if not in the scss file then where? I was hoping there's a way to do it, something that looks like this

```
.btn:hover {
    @if background-color < #222222 {
        color: #000;
    }
    @if background-color >= #222222 {
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe this [article](https://medium.com/dev-channel/using-sass-to-automatically-pick-text-colors-4ba7645d2796) will help you

Comment: He uses a function that takes the color in as a parameter. But I'm wondering if there's any way to get the color value of the element just from selection. What I mean is, I don't want to have to go add this function at the end of every time I change the color.

Comment: I _think_ you'd have to do something like @zgood suggested.  Also, the syntax you propose above could face issues-- say the `.btn` background was transparent and the `body` had a black background?  The sass alone couldn't know that, and might assume it was OK to make the text color black...